# Calculating single day averages over a time series in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm having a hard time finding a starting point for my code, which requires me to take single day averages over a time series. To be more clear, I have an array that includesa date column among other data in a format like this:

```
08/10/1900  100 16 80 8
08/11/1900  158 19 37 1
08/12/1900  105 21 68 7
...
08/10/2013  100 15 75 14
```

And I want to be able to average the values in the column for 08/10, 08/11, and all other dates in the year. So in the end I would have a 366x5 (pesky leap years) array with the averaged values.

I have failed in my search to find a function or method to do this with ease in Matlab, so this is why I'm posting here. I'm imaging there has to be a better way than splitting up my file (it contains ~42,000 rows) by date and creating 365 arrays, then averaging those arrays to place into a new array. So I'm more or less seeking advice on where to start on this function.

Comment: So you want to do it by date of the year. So, Feb 29 will have far fewer rows in your dataset, right? Is every day represented in your dataset?

Comment: Correct, February 29th is only represented 28 times I believe.

Comment: It is a great question. Still thinking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at

- [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) to convert date strings into date vectors. From these vectors you can specify the day of each row.
- [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can be then used to accumulate values for each day seperately. Consider using the function `mean` instead of the default `sum` as the function `fun` applied by `accumarray`.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now -- at least creating daily arrays makes more sense to me. Do you recommend any resources to learn accumarray besides the mathworks page? I would love to learn a bit more about it. Thanks!

Comment: @user3602838 you can find many examples [here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmatlab%5D+accumarray).